# Wordpress 5 returns lots of errors: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: wordpress, typeerror, gallery

No matter what I tried, I still get lots of errors. I tried changing the PHP-Version, disabling pausing/add-ons, inserting lines in the wp-config. Nothing helped. I'm stuck. I'm not able to QuickEdit a page or even create a gallery  [the type of errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhWm1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) You have to tell us more about your Wordpress installation - your installation environment, your WP installation configuration - custom themes, plugins. In case of problems it's usually best to set WP to one of standard built in themes and turn off all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just upgraded to 5.x on the site? You can try disabling Guenberg https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/ temporarily to see if the issue goes away, seems like a conflict with how 5.x renders blocks.

Comment: Thank you! Disabling Gutenberg did minor fixes. Seems like the problem is with the theme and some kind of an incompatibility. I'll try to contact the developer.